# Get product groups and products in laravel error

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to get Product groups and products and show it to blade in laravel like :

x1 (category)
xx1 (product)
xx2 (product)
xx3 (product)
xx4 (product)

z1  (category)
zz1 (product)
zz2 (product)

here is my product group model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductModel::class, 'id');
}
```

and here's my product model :

```
public function product_groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductGroupModel','group_id');
}
```

here's my controller :

```
public function products()
{

    $groups = ProductGroupModel::with(['products'])->get();


    return view('admin.products', ['groups' => $groups]);

}
```

and here's my blade :

```
                                @foreach($groups as $group)
                                <tbody class="text-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class=" d-flex">
                                        <div class="text-end me-2 ms-4 font-weight-bold">
                                            {{$group->name}}
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#" class="ms-3">
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="?action=editgroup&amp;ids=14">
                                            <i class="fas fa-minus-circle text-danger"></i>
                                        </a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody>

                                @foreach($group->products as $products)

                                    <tr>


                                            </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">
                                                        </h6>
                                                        <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{$products->name}}</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0 text-center"><a href="#">xx</a></p>
                                            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0 text-center"><a href="#">xx</a></p>

                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0 text-center">44</p>
                                            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0 text-center">33</p>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle text-center text-sm">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <p class="text-center mb-0"> <i class="text-xs fas fa-search mb-0 "></i> </p>
                                                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0 text-center">show</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach

                                </tbody>
                                @endforeach
```

when I want to show products name in second foreach I get this error

```
Attempt to read property "name" on bool
```

And I really don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake in **products** (plural) method, I assume it should **one to many** relationship

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductModel::class, 'fk_id', 'local_key');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the Products Relationship in Product Group Model is HasMany Types

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->HasMany(ProductModel::class,$foreignKey,$localKey);
}
$foreignKey in Products related to Product Group 
$localKey=Product Group ID
```